# Load .properties file from Class Path in Java

Tags: java

I have to access my .properties file from its class path. Currently I am accessing that from the resources folder directly. But now I want to acess that from the class path.

Current Code:

```
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
try {
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(
            "src/resources/config.properties"));
    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        rate.add(value);
    }
}
}
```

Path of the file is :`src/resources/config.properties`

For deploying the code we are creating war file of the complete project.

Please suggest how can we get this file from the class path.

Answer (score 4):

If your `config.properties` file reside on your same package of your java class then just use,

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

If you put the properties file in any package, then use the package name also

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/your_package_name/config.properties");
```

So the compete code be like,

```
try {
    Properties configProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/config.properties");
    configProperties.load(inputStream);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Could not load the file");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**UPDATE :**
For better understanding see the image.

[image]

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception configProperties.load(inputStream);

Comment: That means `inputStream` is `null`. Could not load. can you show a snapshot where you put the properties file?

Comment: i have a war file from there i want to access the .prop file

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot showing from where you stand and which properties file you want to load ?

Comment: i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can load file from classpath using this

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

If you are dealing with `.properties` files you should consider using `ResourceBundle`

Comment: in the load i have to do the chages ??

Comment: you can do it this way `properties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));`

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception properties.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.pr‌​operties"));

Comment: can you help me getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() about this line

Comment: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` is creating an InputStream from a file located in the resources folder. If you're getting a null pointer exception, it means that the file is not found in the `resources` folder. Is the calling class in the same classpath as your config.properties ?

Answer (score 0):

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
try (final InputStream stream =
           this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("somefile.properties")) {
    properties.load(stream);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.